# Printing interim result of each grinding pass in Python

Tags: python

I have a code that is supposed to print the start value of a variable (duv_idx), the correct interim value of that variable (estimated in a loop based on my keyboard  input) and the end value of the variable after exiting the loop.
However, the interim values do not change as expected. In fact, they do not change at all. How do I need to change my code in order to get the correct interim result printed (i.e. duv_idx = idx + 1 or duv_idx = duv_idx - 1) after each grinding pass?

For example: the input "right arrow", "right arrow", "enter" is supposed to result as the following output in the interactive window:

Start_Idx = 10

New_Idx = 11

New_Idx = 12

End_Idx = 12

```
import keyboard


duv_idx = 10
print('Start_Idx = ', duv_idx)

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "left arrow":
        if duv_idx>1:
            duv_idx = (duv_idx - 1)
            print('New_Idx =', duv_idx)
        else:
            None
    elif keyboard.read_key() == "right arrow":
        if duv_idx<17:
            duv_idx = (duv_idx + 1)
            print('New_Idx =', duv_idx)
        else:
            None    
    elif keyboard.read_key() == "enter":
        break
    else:
        None
        
print('End_Idx = ', duv_idx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue simply seems to be with the names of the keys. If you were to put a print statement inside your conditional blocks for the arrow keys and run the program, you can see that the event is not triggered at all

```py
if keyboard.read_key() == "left arrow":
    print ("key pressed")
```

Replacing `left arrow` with `left` and `right arrow` with `right` however seems to do the trick

```py
while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "left":
        if duv_idx>1:
            duv_idx = (duv_idx - 1)
            print('New_Idx =', duv_idx)
    elif keyboard.read_key() == "right":
        if duv_idx<17:
            duv_idx = (duv_idx + 1)
            print('New_Idx =', duv_idx) 
    elif keyboard.read_key() == "enter":
        break
```

The [api docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api) for the module doesn't seem to have a table of all the key names,
and a from a quick look at the source code it looks like it is creating the key tables dynamically using calls to system APIs. so the names in your case may vary depending on the operating system you're on. But this works on a linux machine.

and another minor note, you don't really need those else blocks you can leave them out.

Comment: Thank you so much, for your help.
Here a small additional aspect that I found out: The names of the keyboard keys might be different according to your language settings. In my case, I used the German setting, so names of the keyboard keys for the arrows were 'nach-links' for left arrow and 'nach-rechts' for right arrow. I got the key names by simply running the line "keyboard.read_key()" and then press the desired key.